# I'm trying to validate all links on a webpage are working. How do I ignore a logout link

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The following method clicks on  all links of our application home page and validates they are working. The problem is the logout link on the page, as you can imagine once I click it they test fails. Is there a way I can ignore or remove the check of the logout link? FYI the logout is the first element in the array. Any help is appreciated

public void checkAllLinks() {

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent().switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
    List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];

    int i = 0;

    // extract the link texts of each link element

    for (WebElement e : linkElements) {

        logger.info(linkTexts[i] = e.getText());

        i++;

    }
    for (String l : linkTexts) {

        driver.findElement(By.linkText(l)).click();

        if (driver.getTitle().equals(title)) {

            System.out.println("\"" + l + "\""

            + " is not Working.");

        } else {

            System.out.println("\"" + l + "\""

            + " is working.");

        }

        driver.navigate().back();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know it's the first, then add a count and skip the first:

```
i = 0;
for (String l : linkTexts) {
    if (i > 0) {
        // ...
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *logout link* from the *list* before clicking all the links

```
  List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

  int logoutlinkIndex;

  for (WebElement linkElement : linkElements) {
           if (linkElement.getText().equals("Log out link text")) {
                       logoutlinkIndex = linkElements.indexOf(linkElement);
                       break;
            }

  }

 linkElements.remove(logoutlinkIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function that goes to the starting page (and logs in, if necessary. (The best option would be to use Page Objects, but that requires more setup on your project)

Rather than using `driver.navigate().back()`, use that function.

(If you can't figure out a way to test if you are on the logon page, find an element on the page, and catch `NoSuchElementException`)